# How to Graphics.DrawImage in Paint event but in a circle shape?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void pictureBoxCroppedImages_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (drawBorder)
    {
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, pictureBoxCroppedImages.ClientRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }

    if (!isRealTimeCropping)
    {
        if (rectImage != null && DrawingRects.Count > 0)
        {
            var dr = DrawingRects.Last();
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(rectImage, dr.Rect);

            if (clearRectangles)
            {
                DrawingRects.Clear();
                pictureBoxImageToCrop.Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    if (isRealTimeCropping && realTimeCroppedImage != null)
    {
        // Draw the real-time cropped image at the relative cursor position
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(realTimeCroppedImage, realTimeCursorPos);
    }
}
```

When it's drawing the image in the bottom in the line:

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(realTimeCroppedImage, realTimeCursorPos);
```

is there any way to keep drawing the image but make the image shape to be circle? now the image as in it's original is a rectangle shape.

I tried this:

```
private void pictureBoxCroppedImages_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (drawBorder)
    {
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, pictureBoxCroppedImages.ClientRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }

    if (isRealTimeCropping && realTimeCroppedImage != null)
    {
        // Handle cropping shape based on radio button selection
        if (radioButtonRectangular.Checked)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(realTimeCroppedImage, 0, 0); // Draw the image at the top-left corner
        }
        else if (radioButtonCircular.Checked)
        {
            using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
            {
                path.AddEllipse(0, 0, realTimeCroppedImage.Width, realTimeCroppedImage.Height);
                e.Graphics.SetClip(path);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(realTimeCroppedImage, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but this version makes it and change it to the shapes i wanted circle or rectangle but now the drawn images are not moving along with the mouse cursor anymore.  and it was moving with the mouse in the first version at the top.
.

Comment: In the second version, why have you changed to `0, 0`? Just do `e.Graphics.DrawImage(realTimeCroppedImage, realTimeCursorPos);` again.

Comment: @Charlieface working thanks.